# Wait for one goroutine to finish

Tags: go, goroutine

I am running a cpu intensive script on 8 different goroutines. Each of these goroutines will take at least a few minutes to complete, and I was wondering if something like this is possible:

```
for i := 0; i < len(input); i += 1 {
  wait_for_number_of_processes_running_to_be_less_than_8
  go calc_math_and_things(input[i])
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup . As far as understand, you always want running processes to be 8. You can achieve that with wait groups

Comment: But if I call `waitgroup.wait()`, it waits for all goroutines to finish. I just want it to wait for any one of them to complete. The wait methods, shown https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup, waits till running subprocesses is 0. I want to wait till its anything less than 8, which I cannot do with waitgroup.

Comment: Technically a waitrgroup waits until its counter is 0. The counter is not based on the number of goroutines, that's just the suggested usage scenario. It's just a counter that you can add to with `Add`, decrement with `Done`, and block until the counter is 0 with `Wait`. You have total control over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a buffered channel to return result of a goroutine and indicate termination, and when you read from this channel you start a new go routine. Something like that:

```
const maxNRoutine = 8
var routineCtr int
var resultCh = make(chan int, maxNRoutine)

for i := 0; i < len(input); i += 1 {
    if routineCtr < maxNRoutines {
        go calc_math_and_things(resultCh, input[i])
        routineCtr++
        continue
    }
    var result = <- resultCh // go routine is done, log result and start a new one
    println(result)
    go calc_math_and_things(resultCh, intput[i])
}
```

Inside your routine:

```
func calc_math_and_things(resultCh chan<- int, input byte) {
     // ... do some stuff
     resultCh <- 1
}
```